# PHP write file from choose from multiply to txt

Tags: php, forms

sorry but i didn't learn PHP yet so can any one help me . i want the out put of the form written in txt file and a messege like " thank you " be the answer if the visitor complete the form and press submit

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="contact-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" id="Name" required>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" id="Email" required>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="Phone" id="Phone">
                         <select name="test">
                            <option selected disabled="disabled"> Where do you live?</option>
                            <option value="test12"> Al Amirat</option>
                            <option value="test13"> Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit"> Submit</button>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                    </form>
```

the last PHP code was to make it to email

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];

$to = 'test@email.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.'  Email: '.$email.'  Phone: '.$phone.'  Subject: '.$subject.'  Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email!";
}

 ?>
```

but after the client need to add the choose from place and making it in txt not email i didn't know how it solved

Comment: How about `file_put_contents`? Do a quick google search on writing files in php and you will get a lot of hits that explain exactly this situation.

Comment: i didn't study PHP yet . but generally thank you perhaps that will open some ways to solve that

Comment: Basically, I would store it as a csv, so do something like this: `$c = file_exists('data.csv') ? file_get_contents('data.csv') : ''; file_put_contents('data.csv', $c . $to . ',' . $subject . ',' . $message . ',' . $headers . '\n')`. The file will be openable in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example,

```
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Check more the example [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php),

There are few things you might get stuck with.

**Folder Permission:**
PHP must have write permission to the folder you are going to save the file. Which 777 permission. So be very careful about security.

**Path Separator**
Path separators are different for linux and windows. So choose accordingly.